# Hochschild cohomology of path algebra as a cohomology of simplicial complex

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, simplicial-complexes, hochschild-cohomology, computational-topology

M. Gerstenhaber and S. D. Schack have shown that a cohomology of simplicial complex can be expressed as a Hochschild cohomology of path algebra constructed from this complex ([link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404983900518)).

Is the opposite true? Suppose, there is a path algebra $\mathbb{K}G$ constructed from digraph $G$. Is it possible to express Hochschild cohomology of $\mathbb{K}G$ as a cohomology of simplicial complex constructed from $G$?

The motivation of this question is the following: there is an optimized algorithm for computation of persistence diagram for cohomology of simplicial complex, and I want to compute persistence diagram for Hochschild cohomology of path algebra constructed from digraph. Therefore, if Hochschild cohomology can be expressed as a simplicial cohomology, then the existing algorithm for persistence diagram computation can be applied.

**UPD:**

- Let assume that $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{C}$. Actually, there is a combinatorial formula for $\text{dim} \text{HH}_0$ and $\text{dim} \text{HH}_1$ obtained by D. Happel ([link](https://tinyurl.com/56dtjm8m)). But ranks is not enough for persistence diagram computation (homology classes expressed in terms of digraph elements are required).
- The basis of $HH_1$ is constructed by L. Guo and F. Li ([link](https://tinyurl.com/ye4c9m79)). It is the disjoint union consisting of 3 subsets:

  1. Derivations for almost oriented cycles (oriented cycles up to the direction of one edge).
  2. Derivations for unoriented cycles.
  3. There is no canonical basis for the third part. It is a quotient of the space of edge derivations by the direct sum of the spaces of vertex and face derivations.

The fact that the basis of $dim HH_1$ is constructed explicitly only partially does not allow to use this basis for computation of persistence diagram. Also, computing elements of such basis for each filtration level (for persistence diagram) is rather time consuming even for small digraphs. So, I am looking for a connection between Hochschild and simplicial cohomology.

Comment: Is $K$ a field? If yes, then Hochschild cohomology is known for finite $G$: Hochschild cohomology of finite-dimensional algebras .

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that the author is Happel.

Comment: @Mare, sorry for a poorly described problem! I added the details to the UPD section of the post.